# Why does IE apply opacity to border-style: dotted?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, border

The title says it all, I've just discovered that IE (9 - 11) automatically applies about 50% opacity to any element's border with `border-style: dotted`.

The weirdest thing is, it only happens on `dotted` in particular, `solid` and `dashed` are fine.

You can test it yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/ptv74f4q/1/

Any ideas?

Comment: Tested in IE9...seems OK...

Comment: I'm using IE11 with document mode set to IE9 through the dev console. Are you on a pure IE9?

Comment: Yes, tested on IE9, v. 9.0.8112.16421

Comment: @TonyBogdanov - That's a really unreliable way to test IE9.  You should look into BrowserStack, Spoon.net or one of the many other browser virtualization environments out there.

Comment: @JoshBurgess Obviously.. Thanks!

Comment: Cannot see any effect on IE 11. Which versions of IE have you actually tested?

Comment: Your text says “applied about 50% opacity to any element with ...”, but do you actually mean just that the dotted *border* looks opaque?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yes, I meant the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be due to IE anti-aliasing the dotted border. If you make the `border-width` bigger than `1px` (say `5px`) the border will appear white again.

One way to get around this would be to overlay some pseudo elements with the same dotted border on top to counteract the opacity:

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #000;
}
span {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    display: inline-block;
    width: 180px;
    height: 85px;
    line-height: 85px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 8px 8px 0 8px;
    border: #fff 1px solid;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
span.dotted {
    border-style: dotted;
}
span.dotted::before, span.dotted::after {    
    border: #fff 1px dotted;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span>I'm with normal border</span>
    <span class="dotted">I'm with dotted border</span>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/oyrbLyjc/1/

**Alternative method**

Alternatively you could try using `border-image`. There are online tools (e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Tools/Border-image_generator) that would be able to help you generate a similar border using this method.